# Error when installing NetMQ via nuget to xamarin projects

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xamarin, nuget, netmq

I tried to install NetMQ to my  xamarin application.

Because NetMQ depends on AsyncIO, this package could not be installed and show me the following error:

```
Could not install package 'AsyncIO 0.1.18'. You are trying to install this 
package into a project that targets '.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile111',
 but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files 
that are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
```

How can I reesolve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The AsyncIO 0.1.18 NuGet package and the NetMQ 3.3.3.1 NuGet package only contain assemblies for .NET 4.0 and .NET 3.5 so you cannot install it into a portable class library project nor a Xamarin project.

Your options include:

1. Port those libraries to the Xamarin frameworks.
2. Only use these libraries on the server side. Your Xamarin project then connects to your server using a supported way, such sending json messages over http.
3. Find another library that does support the Xamarin frameworks.

Comment: Thanks, very clear answer, +1. did you know how to port those libraries to the Xamarin framework.

Comment: Good question. As a start you could try compiling them against the Xamarin framework you are using.

Comment: I formulated this in a question to be more clear. You are very welcome to see it: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37143070/using-zeromq-in-xamarin

Answer (score 1):

NetMQ now target Xamarin IOS and Android, you can download here:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/NetMQ/4.0.0.3-rc3

Comment: Thanks, +1, is targeting windows in your program.

Comment: you mean windows phone? probably not as System.Net.Socket is not available on windows phone

Comment: No I mean Windows UWP (Universal Windows Platform)