# Added reference not detected in visual studio

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget, zeromq, netmq

When trying to install the netmq vis nuget, I get the following error:

```
Could not install package 'AsyncIO 0.1.18'. You are trying to install this package
 into a project that targets '.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile111',
 but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that
 are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
```

The problem is that netmq depends on AsyncIO. when installing it, nuget find that the assembly is not compatible with .Net 4.5.

so nuget fail in installing AsyncIO, and then failed in installing netmq.

So I downloaded the  AsyncIO Source from Github and build it locally with .Net 4.5.

After that and added the dll of AsyncIO built locally as a reference for my project.

Theoretically, NetMQ should be successfully installed with nuget. because I added the needed reference to AsyncIO.

But when trying to reinstall NetMQ, I get the same error:

```
Could not install package 'AsyncIO 0.1.18'. You are trying to install this package
 into a project that targets '.NETPortable,Version=v4.5,Profile=Profile111',
 but the package does not contain any assembly references or content files that
 are compatible with that framework. For more information, contact the package author.
```

and nuget did not detect that I added 'AsyncIO 0.1.18' in my project.

How to let nuget detect that I added this reference in my project?

Comment: Are you using .Net Framework 4.5 or .Net Portable 4.5 to build AsyncIO?

Comment: I am using .Net Framework 4.5 to build it.

Comment: @ThePower: Is there .Net Portable 4.5 ? how to install it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look here:

[.NET Portable profiles](http://embed.plnkr.co/03ck2dCtnJogBKHJ9EjY)

**Profile111** is a combination of:

- .NET Framework 4.5
- Windows 8.0
- Windows Phone 8.1

or in other words:
portable-net45+netcore45+wpa81

So your project into which you are trying to append the NuGet targets Windows Phone 8.1 and other 2 platforms, I mention this one as the most restrictive.

Now let's have a look at the named NuGet package's [source](https://github.com/somdoron/AsyncIO/blob/master/Source/AsyncIO/AsyncIO.csproj):

```
 <ProjectGuid>{3830B7A3-0225-4FDA-B155-E085E183650C}</ProjectGuid> 
 <OutputType>Library</OutputType> 
 <TargetFrameworkVersion>v4.0</TargetFrameworkVersion> 
 <TargetFrameworkProfile> 
 </TargetFrameworkProfile>
```

What do we have here? We can see that the project is not a PCL. It is targeting full .NET 4.0 framework which is not available on **Windows Phone 8.1**. And your library does target Windows Phone 8.1. See the problem?

You say that if you compile the AsyncIO targeting .NET 4.5 than you can successfully append it into your project as a reference? That's not altogether true. I mean you can append a reference to it but you cannot use it. You will see that when you try to call something from that reference.

In order to use AsyncIO from you PCL will have to build AsyncIO as a PCL targeting the same or more restrictive set of platforms. Try creating a PCL project targeting Profile111 and try compiling the AsyncIO code with it (just link the original AsyncIO source files (*.cs) into this new AsyncIO_PCL project). If you are lucky enough and the code of AsyncIO is really compatible you will be able to use that library.

Here are your steps:

1. Create a new project (named AsyncIO_PCL) of type PCL class library.
2. Pick the Profile111 platform set i.e.

   - .NET Framework 4.5
   - Windows 8.0
   - Windows Phone 8.1
3. Link all the .cs files from the original AsyncIO project save one (AssemblyInfo.cs) into the new AsyncIO_PCL project.
4. Set the output assembly name to the same as in original AsyncIO project.
5. Try building the project.

Your ability to build the AsyncIO as a PCL with the required set of supported platforms depends on AsyncIO code i.e. which API is used inside and if that API is supported by all the three platforms you are targeting.

Comment: I rebuild AsyncIO and I changed the target to 4.5. It is built successfully into a dll. After that I added the dll as a reference in my project. The problem is that nuget doesn't detect that I have it installed locally.

Comment: @ProEns08 Read the last paragraph again. You can append a reference to AsyncIO but this reference will not work.

Comment: Yes, you are right: how to add it sucessfully as a reference in my project.

Comment: Your answer is very useful, +1. But, until now I did not resolve the issue.

Comment: @ProEns08 I appended a way of resolution. Try that.

Comment: After trying this, could I use  AsynIO functions and classes?

Comment: @ProEns08 If you are lucky and AsyncIO can be built into a PCL with your set of supported platforms than yes, you will be able to use it for sure.

Comment: very useful as an answer, if I can upvote it for more than one time, I will. but I cannot.

Comment: Could you see my question here, related to the topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37143070/using-zeromq-in-xamarin

Comment: I found that it did not support `System.Net.Sockets` in this PCL profile.

Comment: @ProEns08 have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23477961/cannot-find-system-net-sockets-assembly-for-wp-8-1

Comment: Very useful, I found some interesting answers of yours and I upvote them.

Answer (score -1):

Try clicking right-button on the project -> Properties. In the "Application" menu check the "Target Framework". It should be set to .NET Framework 4.5

Comment: Yes, I did it for building AsyncIO. the problem is that when added the dll of the AsyncIO, it doesn't detect it.

Comment: I hope you understand my problem.

Comment: Why do you add the DLL after installing it through the Nuget? After making an "PM> Install-Package AsyncIO" in the package manager console all your references are set up and you are ready to go. Could you please describe the steps you are taking?

Comment: I reformulated the question.